# Connect two SQL queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

EDITED: I cut the previous SQL query to make things easier - no need to connect both queries as I said previously.

The `stock_tracking_negociacao` table (I filtered only one ticker 'LEVE3' to make things easier):

```
#;data;tipo;mercado;ticker;quantidade;preco;valor
606;2019/12/02;Compra;Mercado à Vista;LEVE3;400;24.95;9980
437;2020/03/19;Compra;Mercado à Vista;LEVE3;100;18.05;1805
775;2021/06/10;Venda;Mercado à Vista;LEVE3;200;35.74;7148
716;2021/08/11;Venda;Mercado à Vista;LEVE3;300;33.6;10080
1214;2022/07/21;Compra;Mercado à Vista;LEVE3;600;23.7;14220
1564;2023/03/13;Compra;Mercado à Vista;LEVE3;200;32;6400
```

where:

- data = date
- tipo: 'Compra' = 'Buy' and 'Venda' = 'Sell'
- quantidade = amount
- preco = price
- valor = amount * price

I need to build a query with the same `stock_tracking_negociacao` table. The table must be orderer by date (`data`) from the oldest to newest records.

My goal is to build two new columns for each line (regardless it appears more than one time): `balance` and `avg_price`.

Explaining the new columns:

1. balance: if `tipo` = `Compra`, we need to add `quantidade` from the previous records. Otherwise, if `tipo` = `Venda`, we need to subtract `quantidade` from the previous records. The first record of each ticker has `balance` = `quantidade`.
2. avg_price: if `tipo` = `Compra`, then `((preco * quantidade) + ([previous] balance * [previous] avg_price)) / (quantidade + [previous] balance)`. If `tipo` = `Venda`, then `avg_price` = `[previous] avg_price`. The first record of each ticker has `avg_price` = `preco`. In MS Excel it's very similar to `SUMPRODUCT`.

Expected result:
[image]

Tks!

Comment: What is the RDBMS? Also, I think you mean table (a db object) not database when referring to "stock_tracking_negociacao".

Comment: I'm using SQLite! Actually the database is a Excel spreadsheet over I'm performing SQL query.

Comment: average of every line, makes no sense an average over a group

Comment: sorry, the average of every line must be calculated since the beggining of the table (older records) until the date of that line/ticker.

Comment: A moving exponential average usually makes more business sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing query is capable of producing the wanted result, I have included the previous quantidade as well, but it does not seem to be needed:

```
WITH RECURSIVE negociacao
AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY ticker, data
            ) AS seq, data, ticker, tipo, preco, quantidade AS qnt
          , coalesce(lag(quantidade) over(partition by ticker
                                 order by data ASC),0) as prev_qnt
    FROM stock_tracking_negociacao
    WHERE tracking IS NULL
    ), adjust_table
AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = 'Compra' THEN qnt ELSE - qnt END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY seq
            ) AS balance
    FROM negociacao
    ), recurse
AS (
    SELECT adjust_table.*, preco AS avg
    FROM adjust_table
    WHERE seq = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT n.*, CASE WHEN n.tipo = 'Compra' THEN ((n.preco * n.qnt * 1.0) + (s.balance * s.avg)) / (n.qnt + s.balance) ELSE s.avg END AS avg
    FROM adjust_table n
    INNER JOIN recurse s ON n.seq = s.seq + 1
        AND n.ticker = s.ticker
    )

SELECT
       *
  --, round(balance * medio, 2) AS valor_total
FROM recurse
```

| seq | data | ticker | tipo | preco | qnt | prev_qnt | balance | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019/12/02 | LEVE3 | Compra | 24.95 | 400 | 0 | 400 | 24.95 |
| 2 | 2020/03/19 | LEVE3 | Compra | 18.05 | 100 | 400 | 500 | 23.57 |
| 3 | 2021/06/10 | LEVE3 | Venda | 35.74 | 200 | 100 | 300 | 23.57 |
| 4 | 2021/08/11 | LEVE3 | Venda | 33.6 | 300 | 200 | 0 | 23.57 |
| 5 | 2022/07/21 | LEVE3 | Compra | 23.7 | 600 | 300 | 600 | 23.7 |
| 6 | 2023/03/13 | LEVE3 | Compra | 32 | 200 | 600 | 800 | 25.775 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O4EDcRFd)

Comment: The average price is a little bit more complex. It must follow [the full code is provided inside the first query in my question]: CASE WHEN n.tipo='Compra' THEN ((n.preco * n.qnt * 1.0) + (s.balance * s.avg)) / (n.qnt + s.balance) ELSE s.avg

Comment: Take a **small** sample of data and manually prepare the actual result that you expect. Include that into your question (there is an edit link under the question). The problem is your case expression contains an average, so it is a circular argument - you want an average, but that formula requires the average. Hence it is NOT clear what you are expecting nor how to get there.

Comment: Done! Edited and included a small sample of the final result I'm expecting.

Comment: I have amended by answer and I believe it matches your expected outcome - but you may be surprised how it does

Comment: Btw, it's just a curiosity: how complex is this query in a scale from 0 (- complex) to 10 (+ complex)? Still learning SQL and I'd like to know the level of this type of structure...

Comment: it shows a very good grasp of SQL IMHO. Usually "complex" just gets way bigger with more tables and joins, so I'm reluctant to put any query into a simple scale because here you are only dealing with a single table. But that does not detract from the skill level demonstrated.